# Django using context processor in email template

Tags: django

I created a custom context processor to display the name of companies in templates. It works correctly in page templates but it is not working in an email template. Nothing is inserted in the template for {{ cname.company_name }}.

The context processor code:

```
def cname(request):
    ti = request.tenant.id
    company = Tenant.objects.get(id=ti)
    return ({'cname': company})
```

The relevant view code:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        password = CustomUser.objects.make_random_password()
        account = form.save(commit=False)
        account.password = make_password(password)
        account.reset_password = True
        account.save()
        account.reset_token = default_token_generator.make_token(account)
        account.save()
        base64_encoded_id = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(account.pk))
        reset_url_args = {'uidb64': base64_encoded_id, 'token': account.reset_token}
        url = self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("password_reset_confirm", kwargs=reset_url_args))
        account_creation_email(account.email, f"{account.full_name}", url=url)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The utils.py code:

```
def account_creation_email(to, full_name, url):
    template = get_template('mail/account-creation.html')
    context = {"full_name": full_name, "url": url}
    html = template.render(context)
    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject="Account Creation Email", body=html, to=[to]
    )
    email.attach_alternative(html, "text/html")
    email.send()
```

The email template:

```
<div>
    <div>Hello, {{ full_name }}</div><br>
    <div>An admin at the company intranet for {{ cname.company_name }} just added an account for you to the site.</div><br>
    <div><a href="{{ url }}">Click Here</a> to set a password and login</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas for getting this to work?

Comment: You only pass `full_name` and `url` to the template via context variable. You need to add it there what you will like to display.

Comment: Marco, I have made various attempts to pass it. Can you give me some hints about how I might pass it to the template?

Comment: Since I don't know what `cname` is, I can't really help. Just üass everything you nee in the template to the `account_creation_email` function and then pass it to the `context` variable.

Comment: What Marco is trying to say is that context processors are only loaded for frontend templates, not when generating e-mails, so you need to explicitly add any variable to the e-mail "context".